# Application error in heroku using java playframework

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I'm trying to publish a Play framework application in Heroku. I followed the instructions from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java). I'm also having the following dependencies

```
   java
   play framework 1.2.4
   mongolab
   morphia 1.6.2a
```

When i open application in the heroku using commang "heroku open". It shows the error as follows..,

```
Oops, an error occured

This exception has been logged with id 6ac06o8hm.
```

But the project runs locally without any issues, pointing to a local MongoDB database.

Exception

```
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]: NullPointerException occure
d : null
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker
.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.JavaExecuti
onException
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Invocation.HTTP Reques
t(Play!)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.CommandRes
ult.getException(CommandResult.java:64)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NullPo
interException
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBPort.che
ckAuth(DBPort.java:308)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBTCPConne
ctor.call(DBTCPConnector.java:201)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.CommandRes
ult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:116)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:303)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 heroku[router]: GET smooth-lightning-41
34.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=
58ms status=500 bytes=417
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBCursor._
hasNext(DBCursor.java:490)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBCursor._
check(DBCursor.java:360)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.google.code.morphi
a.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:255)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.mongodb.DBCursor.h
asNext(DBCursor.java:515)
2012-05-14T10:17:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.modules.morphia.M
odel$MorphiaQuery.asList(Model.java:1320)
```

**UPDATE**

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Fetching custom buildpack... done
-----> Play! app detected
-----> Installing Play! -.....
-----> Error installing Play! framework or unsupported Play! fram
ework version specified. Please review Dev Center for a list of s
upported versions.
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play! app

To git@heroku.com:young-spring-3743.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:young-spring-3
743.git'
```

Comment: Look in the logs for the exception to know what it is

Comment: @MikeMyers I have attached the application logs as part of the posting

Comment: We are able to run the exact same configuration without any issues if we running it locally on our desktop, but the connectivity seems to be broken if the application runs on the Heroku container.

Comment: There is something wrong with you you are using `MONGOLAB_URI` and setting up the connection.  What does the relevant part of your `application.conf` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the logs I can see that there is a null pointer exception, so one of the things as below could be the reason:

1. There is a non initialized variable passed
2. There is a non registered error
3. There is a method call on an empty collection
4. The connection is passed by an empty request

You need to check all the above possibilities.

Comment: @ Mike Its apart from me Your answer is cent percent correct.  I have another problem with heroku.There is no obstacle for pushing app in heroku for past days.But now i found that., but didn't know how it happens. See my update code above

Comment: @malar In stackoverflow never edit your question again. because all the answers will be absurd and wrong. this is one of its rules. I recommend for you to open another distinct question for this.